# How does OwnCloud track "fake" subdirectories in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, owncloud

I wonder, how OwnCloud can track "fake" URLs (e.g. `index.php/apps/files`, which does not exist)? Does it tweak the Apache configuration (or a simple `.htaccess` file)?

I already searched the OwnCloud source code, but did not succeed.

Comment: index.php can look at `PATH_INFO` or `REQUEST_URI` to determine, what to do with a given "fake" request.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at that.

Comment: I just looked at https://github.com/owncloud/core/tree/master/apps/files, so `/apps/files` might not be a good example for a "fake" subdirectory.

Comment: Well, on the system I checked that, `/apps/files` did not exist. I'll try to find another one.

Comment: Sounds like routes to me.  Check out this documentation. https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/installation/changing_the_web_route.html